# What's the deal with the underwater organ?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Is there anything special or significant about the Underwater Organ by the Quaggan town in Caledon forest?

In the times I've swam by it, sometimes there is a chest nearby, and sometimes there is not; is there some way to use the organ to trigger a chest? Is this anything more than a point of interest?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You reveal the chest by playing a certain song on the organ. [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_322382&feature=iv&src_vid=rx4UdIpaCWU&v=l6NaL15cneg) contains the key sequence, which I've also included in a spoiler tag below:

> 2345432
>  231
>  1286

Comment: That's the Guild Wars theme tune. I've also found an organ in the Ebon Hawk fortress. Does that one reveal a chest too?